# Why UITableView's contentLayoutGuide.layoutFrame always zero?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios11

From iOS 11, Apple have added a `contentLayoutGuide` for `UIScrollView`, and I want to add auto layout constraint with table view's `contentLayoutGuide`, but I found `contentLayoutGuide`'s `layoutFrame` is always CGRect.zero, so it does not work.

I want to add a view to the bottom of scroll view's content with auto layout. And this doesn't work:

```
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why this value always zero for `UITableView`, maybe because the subviews of table view were not laid out by auto layout constraints, they were laid out by frame.

So only subviews that laid out by auto layout constraints can give `contentLayoutGuide.layoutFrame` a value.

Answer (score -1):

When are you adding this constraint?

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide/1619657-layoutframe):

> This property contains a valid CGRect value by the time its owning view’s layoutSubviews() method is called.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But it still return zero after owning view’s layoutSubviews() method is called. The value is correct for frameLayoutGuide and safeAreaLayoutGuide, but it always zero for contentLayoutGuide